# Responsive Datatable SQL C# ASP.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I am trying to make a responsive data table where the datatable gathers info from sql using C#. When the table finds not results, the search bar is present and the table is responsive, but as soon as there are results, the results are displayed but the table becomes unresponsive. Here is my code.

This is the Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".table").prepend($("<thead></thead").append($(this).find("tr:first"))).dataTable();
    });


</script>
```

This is the ASP

```
 <asp:GridView cssclass="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive"  runat="server" ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true"
    OnPageIndexChanging="OnPageIndexChanging">
                           <Columns>
                              <asp:BoundField DataField="childs_name" HeaderText="Childs Name" SortExpression="childs_name" >
                              </asp:BoundField>
                               <asp:BoundField DataField="EI_number" HeaderText="EI Number" SortExpression="EI_number" />
                               <asp:BoundField DataField="service_type" HeaderText="Service Type" SortExpression="service_type" />
                               <asp:BoundField DataField="session_section" HeaderText="Attendance Status" SortExpression="session_section" />
                               <asp:BoundField DataField="session_date" HeaderText="Session Date" SortExpression="session_date" />
                               <asp:BoundField DataField="time_from" HeaderText="Start Time" SortExpression="time_from" />
                               <asp:BoundField DataField="time_to" HeaderText="End Time" SortExpression="time_to" />
                               <asp:BoundField DataField="Draft_Final" HeaderText="Note Status" SortExpression="Draft_Final" />
                           </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
```

And this is the code behind in C#

```
string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //GridView1.DataBind();

    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        this.BindGrid();
    }
}

protected void OnPageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    this.BindGrid();
}

private void BindGrid()
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }
            
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1000 childs_name, EI_number, service_type, session_section, session_date, time_from, time_to, Draft_Final FROM session_note_data_tbl where NPI = '" + Session["npi"].ToString() + "'; ", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        da.Fill(dt);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();

        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: You have an empty catch block in your code. This is a very bad idea. What are you trying to accomplish by having that?

Comment: This is temporary while I am writing the the code. Can you explain why this is a bad idea?

Comment: An empty catch block says "I don't care if this code works. If something goes wrong, just ignore the problem. Don't even tell me about it.". Instead, you should catch exceptions *when you can do something about it* or when you need to grab some additional context for logging purposes. You have a few decent options. You can remove the try/catch. You can add some error logging inside the catch block. Or you can some logic in your catch block to show an error label to the user (preferably with some logging so that you can get the full error details for debugging).

Comment: @mason, Thanks, I will look into how I can use this effectively. In the meantime, can you help me figure out this datatable. I am not getting the search and sort functionality with this code.

Answer (score 0):

There are two workarounds for your requirement:

1. You can add `table-responsive` bootstrap class to your GridView so that whenever your GridView has some data and the screen width is about to fill, it will display scroll instead of overflowing and becoming unresponsive.

```
<asp:GridView cssclass="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive></GridView>
```

2. If this doesn't work, the simplest way is to wrap the entire Gridview inside a container

```
<div class="container">
   <asp:GridView cssclass="table table-striped table-bordered></GridView>
</div>
```

or you can also wrap it inside a card

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <div class="card-title">Results</div>
         </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <asp:GridView cssclass="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive></GridView>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried both ways and it is still not working. I have pagination available but sorting and searching is not available.

Comment: @tolyP what is not working? Are you not getting responsive datatable or you are not getting  sorting and searching functionality?

Comment: sorry I was not clear, I am not getting sorting and searching functionality.